# Нужен массив упорядоченный, но из случайных чисел (не сортировка)

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Друзья, я исследую сейчас двоичный поиск (только для упорядоченных массивов). Можно для
этого:

1. отсортировать массив из случайных чисел.
2. вывести массив при помощи цикла, умножая какую либо цифру на следующий индекс 
       массива(это по возрастанию).

Я же хочу вывести массив из случайных чисел, пропуская числа, которые нарушают порядок возрастания/убывания. Полдня проковырялся -- не получается, хотя на первый взгляд просто. Мож кто подскажет. Спасибо.

Comment: И что нужно подсказать?

Comment: Под такими вопросами обычно подразумевается: "Может кто напишет за меня?"

Comment: Думаю, получить равномерно распределенное множество не получится, поскольку каждое следующее число будет зависеть от предыдущего.

Comment: @Ключ, объясните пожалуйста, сортировка почему не подходит ? 

В конце-концов сортировать можно вставками, по ходу формирования массива и например, если нужно, отбрасывать дубликаты.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так

```
bool rand_fill (int * arr, int arr_size){
#if RAND_MAX < INT_MAX
    if (arr_size > RAND_MAX) return false;
#endif
    srand (time(NULL));
    arr[0] = rand()/arr_size;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size - 1; i++) {
        arr[i+1] = rand() % (RAND_MAX - arr[i] - arr_size + i + 2) + arr[i] + 1;    
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Хотя, конечно, все это извращение. Лучше получить массив произвольных рэндомов и потом его отсортировать.

Answer (score 4):

Первый член последовательности получаем рандомом. Каждый последующий - рандом + предыдущий + 1 (если нужно, что бы он был гарантировано больше)

Comment: Если не ограничивать получаемые по random() значения, то переполнение произойдет очень быстро, очередной "следующий" станет меньше предыдущего.

Comment: Всё зависит от реализации рандома:) Я же не писал, что использовать нужно именно random() (такой функции кстати нет, есть rand()). 
Но если использовать rand(), то да, переполнение будет быстро.

Comment: В большинстве \*nix первичен именно random(). Для равномерно распределенных чисел (к этому стремятся при реализации генератора) на каждом шаге будет IMHO (в среднем) добавляться RAND_MAX/2. 

Кстати, в линукс rand() и random() это одна и та же функция.

Comment: А еще в никсах есть замечательные файлы /dev/rand и /dev/srand ...

Comment: @avp в вопросе был с++, а линукса - нет. Давайте не будем притягивать за уши.

@mikillskegg
В каких именно "никсах" есть такой файл?

Comment: Точно есть в линуксе, в opensolaris, кожись, во FreeBSD.

Comment: @KoVadim, а просвятите, читая C++ надо подразумевать Windows ?

Comment: @avp  void question (OS system = Windows);

Comment: Пойду, поменяю свой линукс, нет у меня файла /dev/rand, есть только /dev/random.
Читая с++ нужно понимать кроссплатформенность, если не сказано противоположного.

Comment: О, дико извиняюсь./dev/random и /dev/urandom. Склероз.

Comment: ln -s спасет Вас.

Answer (score 2):

В вопросе ключевые слова "пропуская числа, которые нарушают порядок возрастания/убывания", т.е. массив *уже* заполнен. В общем задача сводится к нахождению наибольшей возрастающей/убывающей подпоследовательности, вот ниже алгоритм для нахождения наидлиннейшей возрастающей подпоследовательности за квадратичное время, есть способ за n*log(x), если надо в гугле есть

```
int d[MAXN], p[MAXN]; // константа MAXN равна наибольшему возможному значению n

for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    d[i] = 1;
    p[i] = -1;
    for (int j=0; j<i; ++j)
        if (a[j] < a[i])
            if (1 + d[j] > d[i]) {
                d[i] = 1 + d[j];
                p[i] = j;
            }
}

int ans = d[0],  pos = 0;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    if (d[i] > ans) {
        ans = d[i];
        pos = i;
    }
cout << ans << endl;

vector<int> path;
while (pos != -1) {
    path.push_back (pos);
    pos = p[pos];
}
reverse (path.begin(), path.end());
for (int i=0; i<(int)path.size(); ++i)
    cout << path[i] << ' ';
```

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо за ответы и коменты.
Андрей написал мне: Под такими вопросами обычно подразумевается: "Может кто напишет за меня?"
Нет, Андрей, у меня нет необходимости выдавать чужое за свое, мне 52 года, ни в каком учебном заведении я не учусь. Моя цель научиться самому, в том числе и с помощью работ других людей. Когда я начинал изучать С++(сейчас я освоил 11 уроков из 22-х), то стремился сам все решать, в итоге очень много тратил времени, в 
частности задачу "Как стать миллионером"(телеигра), я делал более месяца(практически каждый день пыхтел над этой задачей) и хотя от этого огромная польза, всеже расход времени скажем так, лишний. Теперь если относительно быстро чтото не получается ищу
ответ в и-нете(исключительно вцелях экономии времени) потом стараюсь отработать до автоматизма. По поводу моего вопроса. Есть ваши ответы, которые, что бы понять у меня пока просто не хватает  знаний. Самый шикарный ответ дал мне Mikillskegg, все предельно понятно, но я обнаружил подводный камень в этом алгоритме: допустим делаем массив по возрастанию, если первое или любое(по индексу) случайное число есть максимально возможное число диапазона rand(), далее возрастания не получится. Почему именно таким образом я решил вывести упорядоченную последовательность из случайных чисел, ведь есть
другие способы, просто тестирую разные способы. Здесь обнаружил подводный камень -- польза.

Comment: Респект за то, что несмотря на возраст взялись за новое дело.

Но я сделал программу так, что указанная Вами ошибка не произойдет. Повнимательнее почитайте код. Никогда не будет одинаковых чисел. Если не поймете, при возможности объясню.

Comment: Молодец @Ключ !

@mikillskegg, в винде RAND_MAX = 32767. Что-то не соображу, что будет для  arr_size > RAND_MAX ?

Comment: Можно просто ввести в начале функции проверку, чтобы arr_size <= RAND_MAX. В противном случае просто не получится сделать то, что хочет @Ключ. Я собственно такую проверку и вставил сначала, потом убрал, потому что думал, что размер RAND_MAX везде такой же, как и в лине, т.е. == INT_MAX. 

А то, что написал @Ключ, в моем алгоритме не произойдет. Можете проверить. Я такой вариант учитывал. @avp, Вы, я думаю, вполне в силах сообразить исходя из текста программы.

Comment: Не найду, что написал @Ключ, но мне кажется,  что при **большом** arr_size в элементы массива будут помещаться последовательно вычисляемые суммы всех rand(). Переполнение для RAND_MAX = 32767 произойдет (?) не соображу.

Comment: Ну да, при больших arr_size поначалу будет несколько произвольных значений, а потом пойдут просто последовательные числа. При arr_size==RAND_MAX массив будет заполнен последовательными числами от 1 до RAND_MAX или от 0 до RAND_MAX-1 (но такой случай в данном алгоритме будет очень редок).

Answer (score 1):

Первый член массива = random(10), второй - random(20)+10 и т.д в цикле.

Comment: Скорее уж random(10)+10. =)  
Хотя все равно довольно топорно.

Comment: Уважаемый mikillskegg, ваш код на этой странице мне непонятен
из-за нехватки знаний. Мне Хэшкод прислал на электронную почту 
другой вариант вашего кода, на этой странице почемуто нет его,
он мне понятен, правда я его переделал по своему взял только
идею. Внутри цикла for, при помощи цикла do{...}while используя соответствующее его условие, подбираем нужные числа и выводим их внешним циклом for. В каком из двух ваших кодов указанная ошибка не произойдет?

Comment: Код, сейчас лежащий на сайте, более правильный. Что именно непонятно?

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int
fill (int *a, int size)
{
  if (size < 1)
    return 0;
  int i,
    d = INT_MAX/size;

  a[0] = rand()%d;
  for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
    a[i] = a[i-1] + rand()%d +1;

  return 1;
}

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int n = 10;
  if (ac > 1)
    if ((n = atoi(av[1])) <= 0)
      n = 1;
  int i, *a = malloc(n*sizeof(*a));

  srand(time(0));
  fill(a,n);
  for (i = 0; i < ((n > 3)? 3:n); i++)
    printf ("a[%d] %d\n",i,a[i]);
  if (n > 3) 
    for (i = n-2; i < n; i++)
      printf ("a[%d] %d\n",i,a[i]);
}
```

Далее широкое поле для модификации fill() (можно добавить min, max или предел d и т.п.).

Тренируйтесь, [@Ключ](/users/4513/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87).

Comment: Для компиляции g++ добавьте:

   #include  <time.h>

и исправьте ...\*a = malloc(... на:

   ... *a = (int *)malloc(...